# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in dynamic field web browser

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, browser

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

i am new using dynamic field and append , i want to show option that i get from my database, the option dropdown is laoded but there is an error
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

here is my code:

```
<script>


$(document).ready(function(){  
      var i=1;
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           i++;  
           $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'" valign="middle" style="height:45px;">\
                <td width="10%" style="text-align:right; padding-right:20px;">\
                    <select class="form-control" id="type" name="type" onchange="">\
                      <?php
                            while ($rowType = mysql_fetch_array($resultQueryType))
                            {
                                echo "<option value='".$rowType['type_name']."'>".$rowType['type_name']." </option>";
                            }
                        ?>\
                    </select>\
                </td>\
                <td width="35%">\
                <select class="form-control" id="antenna" name="antenna" onchange="">\
                      <option value="">-- None --</option>\
                </select>\
                </td>\
                <td width="15%" style="padding-left:20px;">\
                    <select class="form-control" id="antenna_qty" name="antenna_qty" onchange="">\
                    <?php test(); ?>\
                    </select>\
                </td>\
                <td width="15%" style="text-align:center;"><label>0</label></td>\
                <td width="15%" style="text-align:center;"><label>0</label></td>\
                <td><center><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></center></td>\
            </tr>');
      });
      $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
           var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
           $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
      });  
      $('#submit').click(function(){            
           $.ajax({  
                url:"name.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:$('#add_name').serialize(),  
                success:function(data)  
                {  
                     alert(data);  
                     $('#add_name')[0].reset();  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 });  
</script>
```

here is screenshoot web browser said [syntaxerror: missing )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtuJ0.png)

did i do wrong?

Comment: look at the code in the browser (view source) to see what the browser is receiving

Comment: Your PHP is echoing embedded unescaped single quote characters, but your JS is trying to use single quotes around the full string.

Comment: The is a single quote on the line with </tr> that shouldn't be there

Comment: @JaromandaX from view souce the problem is in this line   
$('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'" valign="middle" style="height:45px;">\

Comment: is it? can't see it myself, nor the whole content of the script tag *as it appears to the browser* - so, yeah, that's not very helpful at all

Comment: Edit the question and add the code the browser has. Also why the backslashes at the end of the lines (maybe some JS syntax I'm unfamiliar with?)?

Comment: @chris85 i edit it,do it give you more information? backslash in the end of the line means like "+" , its continue the line above

Comment: As @nnnnnn said the issue is your single quote on the attribute here, `<option value='`. That is closing the javascript encapsulation from here `append('`. (I'm here from the PHP, the backslash trick is strange)

Comment: @chris85 allright , thankyou very much for the help, now i know the problem, i'll try to solve it...

Comment: @nnnnnn also thankyou from the start hahaha