# How to input fetch in a function, got Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token on web browser

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, browser

I'm new in php query javascript code, I want to make a function for

```
while ($rowAnt = mysql_fetch_array($resultQueryAntenna))
            {
                echo "<option value=\'".$rowAnt['Antenna']."\'>".$rowAnt['Antenna']." </option>";
            }
```

so I can use it in many area, but I got this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in the web browser

This is web browser (source) error: [web browser(source) error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGwIh.png)

This is my code :

```
`$resultQueryAntenna = mysql_query($queryAntenna) or die(mysql_error()."`[".$queryAntenna."]");

function test1(){
     while ($rowAnt = mysql_fetch_array($resultQueryAntenna))
        {
            echo "<option value=\'".$rowAnt['Antenna']."\'>".$rowAnt['Antenna']." </option>";
        }
}
<script>


$(document).ready(function(){  
      var i=1;
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           i++;  
           $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'" valign="middle" style="height:45px;">\
                <td width="10%" style="text-align:right; padding-right:20px;">\
                    <select class="form-control" id="type" name="type" onchange="">\
                      <?php
                            while ($rowType = mysql_fetch_array($resultQueryType))
                            {
                                echo "<option value=\'".$rowType['type_name']."\'>".$rowType['type_name']." </option>";
                            }
                        ?>\
                    </select>\
                </td>\
                <td width="35%">\
                <select class="form-control" id="antenna" name="antenna" onchange="">\
                      <option value="">-- None --</option>\
                      <?php test1();?>\
                </select>\
                </td>\
                .........................................
```

Did I do something wrong? My code inside the function works if I don't put them in a function.

Comment: is this code **any** different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44402535/syntaxerror-missing-after-argument-list-in-dynamic-field-web-browser ?

Comment: @JaromandaX no different, but that problem already solved, this time i got different error when i want to put them in a function

Comment: _"but i got this error Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in the web browser"_ - your screenshot clearly shows that the output of your script contains PHP error messages ... of course those “break” the JavaScript syntax. So, go fix those (and please do _research_ them before you ask any follow-up question on that - those get discussed all the time.)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try declaring i variable inside the function. It might work I'm not sure,

I can't comment as I don't have 50 reputations.

Answer (score 0):

You can't break a string over multiple lines in JavaScript.

You could concatenate them, like this:

```
$('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'" valign="middle" style="height:45px;">'
  + '<td width="10%" style="text-align:right; padding-right:20px;">'
  + ...
```

Or, if you use ECMAScript 6, you can use template strings:

```
$('#dynamic_field').append(`<tr id="row'+i+'" valign="middle" style="height:45px;">
  <td width="10%" style="text-align:right; padding-right:20px;">
  ...`
```

Comment: umm for "+" sign , have no different fucntion with "\" , i already tried the "+" one